# Bigint vs varchar datatype. Should I match source system?

Tags: sql-server, best-practices, etl

Unfortunately, I think this is an opinion question.  But I'd like to know if there is a best practice.

Our datawarehouse uses a bigint as a primary key for an address table. The existing records all came from a source system that used a bigint, so it matched.  We have a new source system that now uses a varchar value for the identity.  It's still just a number, and doesn't have any collisions with the old system.  And doesn't use leading zeros or anything.  The data comes in as a json message and we parse out the information.  so there isn't any joining between the systems.   So should we change our DW key to be varchar to match, or say screw it and just convert to bigint on the import.

Also, the update won't be that risky or affect many other processes.

One other piece of information, old source system was websphere.  New source is C4/SAP.

Comment: You decide if it is a **wise** idea to assume that string will always and only contain numeric characters, that any leading spaces are not significant and that the source system, over which you have zero control, will never ever change.

Comment: Is this a one-time load or will it happen multiple times? Will the source change again or will it stay the same? Consider looking at an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) or ELT (Extract, Load, Transform)  approach where you analyse the data before you load it into the Data Warehouse. e.g. SSIS, DTS, ...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was said in the comments, you should also consider that the wrong data types can also severely affect performance when [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) has to take place in a way that significantly affects the [cardinality estimates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) of your predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses).

When [implicit conversion causes cardinality estimate issues on your predicates](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-monitor/when-sql-server-performance-goes-bad-implicit-conversions) you will likely run into sub-optimal execution plans using less than ideal operators to locate, filter, and merge the data together. So it's important you also consider *how* you will be using the primary key of your `address` table. I assume it is joined on?...If so, you must also analyze the data type of the joining column. If you plan to change from a `BIGINT` to a `VARCHAR` in your `address` table, then you should probably do the same wherever else that column is referenced, especially as a predicate.

And as SMor mentioned, it appears you're importing data from a system you don't have control over, so generally you do want to match the source data type, at least for the initial load step. You can always try to normalize it with a secondary step / process. But again, if you need to change the data type on the `address` table, you should also think about where else that column is being referenced, and likely should update the data types of those referencing fields as well.

Comment: We are aware of the implicit conversions.  I asked the same question on stackoverflow and got this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576129/bigint-vs-varchar-datatype-should-i-match-source-system?noredirect=1#comment126505171_71576129

Comment: @DaytonBrown Yes that's also true. If you have the ability to create surrogate keys for your data warehouse, that's a good architecture to follow. All things to consider.